# Select hosts from Ansible inventory based on value of host variable

Tags: dynamic, ansible, jinja2, hostvars

I am trying to set up a client and server using Ansible that need to connect to each other (Wireguard client and server in this case). Since the server needs to know the peers that will connect to it, I'm looking to gather a list of hosts that the server will be able to create a peer entry for in its configuration. The list should be dynamically generated (there could be multiple clients connecting to the same server) and generated based on the `target_server` variable assigned to each client, the value of which should be equal to the `inventory_hostname` of the server it needs to connect to. The jinja2 expression I am using in the MWE below unfortunately keeps coming up empty, but I'm unsure how to improve it.

### Playbook

```yaml
- name: Set up Wireguard Server
  hosts: servers
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Figure out peers for this server
      become: false
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ groups['servers'] | select('match', 'target_server={{ inventory_hostname }}') | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname') | list }}"
```

### Inventory

```yaml
servers:
  hosts:
    Wireguard-Server:
      ansible_host: 2.3.4.5

clients:
  hosts:
    Wireguard-Client-1:
      ansible_host: 1.2.3.4
      target_server: Wireguard-Server
    Wireguard-Client-2:
      ansible_host: 4.3.2.1
      target_server: Different-Server
```

### Log

```
TASK [Figure out peers for this server] ********************************************
skipping: [Wireguard-Server] =>
  skipped_reason: No items in the list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the dictionary of the clients and target_server

```yaml
  clients: "{{ dict(groups.clients|
                    zip(groups.clients|
                        map('extract', hostvars, 'target_server'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  clients:
    Wireguard-Client-1: Wireguard-Server
    Wireguard-Client-2: Different-Server
```

Use it to select the matching clients

```yaml
  my_clients: "{{ clients|dict2items|
                  selectattr('value', 'eq', inventory_hostname)|
                  map(attribute='key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_clients:
  - Wireguard-Client-1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: servers

  vars:

    clients: "{{ dict(groups.clients|
                      zip(groups.clients|
                          map('extract', hostvars, 'target_server'))) }}"
    my_clients: "{{ clients|dict2items|
                    selectattr('value', 'eq', inventory_hostname)|
                    map(attribute='key') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: clients

    - debug:
        var: my_clients
```

---

You can select all hosts from the inventory that match *target_server*

```yaml
  my_clients: "{{ hostvars|dict2items|
                  selectattr('value.target_server', 'defined')|
                  selectattr('value.target_server', 'eq', inventory_hostname)|
                  map(attribute='key') }}"
```